# Automatically write readRDS() statements from saveRDS() statements

Tags: r, emacs, data-munging

I often write `saveRDS()` statements after a good deal of data munging and this prompts me to immediately write `readRDS()` for future, reproducible coding accessing the .RDS files for faster loading into `R`.  My manual process for generating `readRDS()` statements from the typed `saveRDS()` statements is outlined below.  How can it be improved?  How can I write a macro/function to do this for me, in `EMACS` and/or `R`?

```
## I type these out:
saveRDS(dems,"./_00_data_original/dems.RDS")
saveRDS(meds,"./_00_data_original/meds.RDS")
saveRDS(anti,"./_00_data_original/anti.RDS")

## Then I rectangle kill (C-x-r-k) the file names and commas
## and rectangle yank (C-x-r-y) them on the left hand side
## note:  depends on filenames being equal lengths
dems,saveRDS("./_00_data_original/dems.RDS")
meds,saveRDS("./_00_data_original/meds.RDS")
anti,saveRDS("./_00_data_original/anti.RDS")

## then I Esc-Shift-5 to query replace ",saveRDS" with " <- readRDS"
dems <- readRDS("./_00_data_original/dems.RDS")
meds <- readRDS("./_00_data_original/meds.RDS")
anti <- readRDS("./_00_data_original/anti.RDS")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways I can think of are using a macro or multiple cursors.

### Macro

I often create macros that work on a single line, and the last action of the macro is to move down to the next line, so I can repeat it quickly.

In this case after you copied and pasted the saveRDS blocks, on the first line: begin recording a macro and perform these actions:

1. goto beginning of line
2. move forward two words
3. mark and cut word behind the cursor
4. erase the comma
5. goto beginning of line
6. yank
7. insert "<- read"
8. delete the next 4 characters (save)
9. move down 1 line.
10. stop recording macro

The key is to record the macro in a way that it will be able to apply genericaly to all lines with the given format. Making sure lines where the filename is something like "foo-bar baz" can be transformed by the macro as well as simple filenames like "bar" by using things like `forward-word` or `forward-sexp` instead of moving character by character.

Then you can use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to run the macro, on the next line, and just press <kbd>e</kbd> to run it again on the next lines until done. You use a prefix argument too, so if you know you want to apply it to 10 lines, then you can use <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>10</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>

Here I record the macro on the first line, wait a second, then quickly apply it to both lines below.

[image]

You can save this macro in your init by using `name-last-kbd-macro` and `insert-kbd-macro` and use it like a command in future sessions.

### Multiple Cursors

Or you can use multiple cursors, this will allow you to perform the same action as the macro, but on all the lines at the same time.

https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use something like this:

```
saveRead <- function(..., path, prefix = "", envir = .GlobalEnv) {
  dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
  objs <- sapply(dots, deparse)
  new_objs <- paste0(prefix, objs)
  paths <- file.path(path, paste0(objs, ".RDS"))
  invisible(lapply(seq_along(objs), function(x) {
    saveRDS(get(objs[x], envir = envir), file = paths[x])
    assign(new_objs[x], readRDS(paths[x]), envir = envir)
  }))
}
```

Here's an example. I'm just writing to a `tempdir`, but you would enter your actual desired directory. Also, for the sake of demonstration, I've prefixed the object name (on re-read) with "test_". Set `prefix` to `""` (default) to keep the original name.

```
a <- 1:2
b <- 3:4
ls()
# [1] "a"        "b"        "saveRead"

x <- tempdir()
list.files(x, ".RDS")
# character(0)

saveRead(a, b, path = x, prepend = "test_")
ls()
# [1] "a"        "b"        "saveRead" "test_a"   "test_b"   "x"       
list.files(x, ".RDS")
# [1] "a.RDS" "b.RDS"
```

---

To reproduce your actions, it could be used like:

```
saveRead(dems, meds, anti, path = "./_00_data_original")
```